# Is this achievable using left joins in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

**t_voucher**

- id
- title
- description

**t_used_voucher**

- id
- customerid
- date_used

I want to get results for all vouchers that have NOT been used by `customerid`

Is this even possible in SQL or an alternative approach ?

The closest, I can get is something like this, but I don't think I can filter by `customerid`

```
SELECT
    t_voucher.id, t_voucher.title,
    t_voucher.description,
    t_used_voucher.customerid
FROM
    t_voucher
LEFT JOIN 
    t_used_voucher ON t_voucher.id = t_used_voucher.id
WHERE
    t_used_voucher.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT v.id, v.title, v.description, uv.customerid
FROM t_voucher v LEFT JOIN
     t_used_voucher uv
     ON v.id = uv.id AND
        uv.customerid = @customerid
WHERE uv.id is null;
```

Comment: Great this works fine. But I guess it can only work as a stored procedure ?